# jQuery's native ajax function vs ajaxDotNet plugin

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm using jQuery with ASP.NET 3.5 and the ajaxDotNet plugin. What are the differences are between these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ajaxDotNet plugin](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxdotnet/) uses the jQuery's native ajax functions but it is specifically designed for calling ASP.NET PageMethods and JSON enabled web services.

Comment: Thanx darin! if u dont mind me asking if there is any reason why one can't use jquery.ajax() to achieve the same? I've seen some posts on Dave Wards site (Encosia) where he calls page methods with jquery.ajax() - if Im not mistaken.

Would you recommend using the ajaxDotNet plugin then for Page Methods and WServices over jquery.ajax()?

Comment: @Darin, I know this is a very old Question, but I think you're wrong. I was just reading the ajaxDotNet source, and it does NOT use native jQuery ajax funtions. In fact, aside from attaching itself as a method of the jQuery object, it only uses jQuery for `$.each` and `$.extend`. Everything else, including the XHR stuff, looks custom -  which seems silly. I'll echo @Shalan's comment and ask, is there any reason to use ajaxDotNet instead of `jQuery.ajax`.